# Apply same string status to all rows with similar application id and user id

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

For different combinations `user_status_1` and `user_status_2` and `application_status=='complete'` I have created an ultimate status, namely `final_status`. I want to apply the same `final_status` to all rows with same `application_id` and `user_id`. Please check beneath for a desired outcome.

**My dataset**

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.table(application_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 user_id = c(123,123,123,456,456,456,789,789,789), 
                 date = c("01/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "03/01/2018"),
                 application_status = c("incomplete", "details_verified", "complete"),
                 user_status_1 = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"),
                 user_status_2 = c("a","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

**With outcome**

```
 application_id user_id       date application_status user_status_1 user_status_2
              1     123 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             a
              1     123 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             b
              1     123 2018-01-03           complete             z             c
              2     456 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             d
              2     456 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             e
              2     456 2018-01-03           complete             z             f
              3     789 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             g
              3     789 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             h
              3     789 2018-01-03           complete             z             i
```

**My unsuccessful effort**

```
df %>% group_by(application_id, user_id) %>%
  mutate(final_status = case_when(any(
    application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "c" ~ "good",
    application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "f" ~ "great",
    application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "i" ~ "excellent"
    )))
```

**Desired outcome *(scroll horizontally to view all columns)***

```
application_id user_id       date application_status user_status_1 user_status_2 final_status
              1     123 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             a         good
              1     123 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             b         good
              1     123 2018-01-03           complete             z             c         good
              2     456 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             d        great
              2     456 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             e        great
              2     456 2018-01-03           complete             z             f        great
              3     789 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             g    excellent
              3     789 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             h    excellent
              3     789 2018-01-03           complete             z             i    excellent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You came close – you simply need to wrap each of the logical statements with `any`.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(application_id, user_id) %>%
  mutate(final_status = case_when(
    any(application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "c") ~ "good",
    any(application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "f") ~ "great",
    any(application_status == "complete" & user_status_1 == "z" & user_status_2 == "i") ~ "excellent"
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option by creating a `named` vector first

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- setNames(c('good', 'great', 'excellent'), 
             c('completezc', 'completezf', 'completezi'))
nm2 <- do.call(paste0, df[4:6])
setDT(df)[, final_status := nm1[nm2]][,
    final_status := final_status[complete.cases(final_status)], 
            .(application_id, user_id)]
df
#   application_id user_id       date application_status user_status_1 user_status_2 final_status
#1:              1     123 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             a         good
#2:              1     123 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             b         good
#3:              1     123 2018-01-03           complete             z             c         good
#4:              2     456 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             d        great
#5:              2     456 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             e        great
#6:              2     456 2018-01-03           complete             z             f        great
#7:              3     789 2018-01-01         incomplete             x             g    excellent
#8:              3     789 2018-01-02   details_verified             y             h    excellent
#9:              3     789 2018-01-03           complete             z             i    excellent
```

---

Or do a join in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    unite(newcol, !!! rlang::syms(names(.)[4:6]), sep="") %>% 
    filter(str_detect(newcol, '^complete')) %>% 
    transmute(application_id, user_id, final_status = nm1[newcol]) %>%
    right_join(df)
```